rspec-rails prevent rails generator
i setup rspec-rails as below
# Gemfile
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", '~> 6.1.0'
end

$ bundle install
$ rails generate rspec:install

# .rspec
--require 'rails_helper'

I just replace --require spec_helper by --require rails_helper (rails_helper required spec_helper anyway) in order to no need to require 'rails_helper' on every .spec class.
Now i run rspec and it run ok, but when i generate new model, rspec stuck
rails g model problem name:string
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20240422135433_create_problems.rb
      create    app/models/problem.rb
      invoke    rspec
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rails db:migrate

You have 1 pending migration:

db/migrate/20240422135433_create_problems.rb

rspec still work (as expected that it will show that it will remove the model spec file even this file is not created due to above issue) when delete model:
rails d model problem name:string
      invoke  active_record
      remove    db/migrate/20240422135433_create_problems.rb
      remove    app/models/problem.rb
      invoke    rspec
      remove      spec/models/problem_spec.rb

i reverted .rspec file and back to default rspec style, but i still don't know why, and is there any solution for using .rspec to auto require helpers (ex: rails_helper) for all spec files ?

I am not certain I understand what the question is here? There is no need to add that configuration. When you generate a model rspec-rails will automatically add the require 'rails_helper' line to the spec file See Here

@engineersmnky, yes, but we will manually create many other .spec files, right ? so i though just put --require 'rails_helper' to .rspec file then i no need to add it anymore.

I see. If you are manually creating files then I would recommend just ensuring the require 'rails_helper' is present. You can also generate most rails related specs using the built in generators
